# My Google Apps Script time-based trigger refuses to work, even though it displays no errors

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Spreadsheet-bound Script that contains a Time-based Trigger that is supposed to run a function `'update ()'`. This trigger needs to be activated manually at first, but it is meant to run indefinitely so that's not a problem for me.

The `'update ()'` function, upon being executed directly from within Apps Script, runs with no hiccups, doesn't display any error, and usually finishes its execution in under 10s; the Spreadsheet the Script is bound to also doesn't display any errors, and the outcome happens as intended.

I utilize another function, called `'updateClock3am ()'`, to actually activate the trigger, and it also runs with no hiccups, displaying no errors, and usually with an execution time under 2ms. The code for that function is as follows:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('update')
     .timeBased()
     .everyDays(1)
     .atHour(3)
     .nearMinute(15)
     .create;
```

But even though no errors are displayed, the trigger doesn't work at all. I tried using the following code to check how many Triggers are running on the project and the output is always zero:

```
let count = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().length; 
Logger.log(count);  // 0
```

I've also tried renaming the function, changing the time the function should run at, copying the original document and seeing if the trigger works there, nothing yielded any error message nor did the trigger actually work any of those times.

I am aware of the Google Services Quotas, and my account should be nowhere near the quotas; but just to be sure, I created a fresh new account and used it to run the trigger and then count triggers to no avail. I thought maybe the issues was just the count active triggers part, and thus I waited until the next day and nope, the update function hadn't been triggered. I got no email reporting execution failures in either account.

[This](https://script.google.com/d/1mroR6T1xXRj6MGfTtVYwig6ocympslac7qdHq_5Wh77hklOkJlJilkDU/edit?usp=sharing) is not the full script and doesn't include the secondary functions being called by the `'update ()'` function, but is an exact copy of the relevant part of the code (my comments for you guys are in purple, I don't really know what purple comments are supposed to mean in Javascript but I used them just for this example).

The thing that really messes with me is that I've done pretty much this same trigger setup on another Spreadsheet and had no issues at all:
[trigger that actually works, in another Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORL8a.png) (this trigger also shows up when
I count active project triggers, unlike the one that doesn't work)

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sincerely getting a bit desperate here, maybe it's just something really easy and dumb that I'm missing, but I've spent way longer than I'd like to admit trying to make this work.
If any more code is necessary, I can link the original Spreadsheet here for anyone that would like to make a copy (but a lot of the Apps Script code is otherwise unrelated to this specific issue).

Thanks in advance!

*I also asked this question in Reddit r/googlesheets*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one small error:

.create should be .create();

Comment: Cooper, thank you so much. It's been three days and I didn't spot that little mistake.